# How Can I Allow Multiple Users to Input Via Userform Without Overwriting Conflict

Tags: excel, vba

I have created a shared workbook containing a userform that has VBA code to transfer  input data to a worksheet.  However, when multiple users enter data a Resolve Conflict dialog box is displayed as follows:

Your changes on sheet "SrOfcSpc" changed cell A4 from '' to '4/15/2016'
  Conflicting changes by John Doe -- 4/11/16 3:44PM changed cell A4 from 
    '' to '4/11/2016'

How can I prevent this from happening so that multiple users can input at the same time?  Below is a snippet of my existing code.  Thank you.

```
lrCD4 = Sheets("SrOfcSpc").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Sheets("SrOfcSpc").Cells(lrCD4 + 1, "A").Value = TextBox43.Text
Sheets("SrOfcSpc").Cells(lrCD4 + 1, "B").Value = TextBox44.Text
Sheets("SrOfcSpc").Cells(lrCD4 + 1, "C").Value = TextBox25.Text
Sheets("SrOfcSpc").Cells(lrCD4 + 1, "D").Value = TextBox26.Text
Sheets("SrOfcSpc").Cells(lrCD4 + 1, "E").Value = TextBox27.Text
Sheets("SrOfcSpc").Cells(lrCD4 + 1, "F").Value = TextBox31.Text
Sheets("SrOfcSpc").Cells(lrCD4 + 1, "G").Value = TextBox23.Text
Sheets("SrOfcSpc").Cells(lrCD4 + 1, "H").Value = TextBox24.Text
Sheets("SrOfcSpc").Cells(lrCD4 + 1, "I").Value = TextBox29.Text
Sheets("SrOfcSpc").Cells(lrCD4 + 1, "J").Value = TextBox30.Text
Sheets("SrOfcSpc").Cells(lrCD4 + 1, "K").Value = TextBox195.Text
Sheets("SrOfcSpc").Cells(lrCD4 + 1, "L").Value = TextBox196.Text
Sheets("SrOfcSpc").Cells(lrCD4 + 1, "M").Value = TextBox204.Text
Sheets("SrOfcSpc").Cells(lrCD4 + 1, "N").Value = TextBox203.Text
Sheets("SrOfcSpc").Cells(lrCD4 + 1, "O").Value = TextBox200.Text
Sheets("SrOfcSpc").Cells(lrCD4 + 1, "P").Value = TextBox199.Text
Sheets("SrOfcSpc").Cells(lrCD4 + 1, "Q").Value = TextBox198.Text
Sheets("SrOfcSpc").Cells(lrCD4 + 1, "R").Value = TextBox197.Text
Sheets("SrOfcSpc").Cells(lrCD4 + 1, "S").Value = TextBox202.Text
Sheets("SrOfcSpc").Cells(lrCD4 + 1, "T").Value = TextBox201.Text
Sheets("SrOfcSpc").Cells(lrCD4 + 1, "U").Value = TextBox205.Text
```

Comment: Use a database, or have everyone enter data on a different sheet.  http://blog.contextures.com/archives/2008/11/18/avoiding-shared-workbooks-in-excel/

Comment: I tried the option of having everyone's data go to a different sheet but it doesn't work.  I have the userform setup with multiple tabs (i.e., Recruiter, etc.) and the user chooses the applicable tab based on their role type.  So even is Recruiter #1 inputs their data and it writes to a separate sheet for recruiter1, if I try and direct the vba code for Recruiter2 to go a separate tab for them it is still directed to the sheet for Recruiter 1 because they are both using the same textbox fields on the UserForm.  Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

In case it helps someone else seeking a solution.  I found the below solution from a user on another job board that does the trick.

```
Private Sub Save_Click()
ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("sheetname").Activate
Range("A1").Select
Do
If IsEmpty(ActiveCell) = False Then
ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
End If
Loop Until IsEmpty(ActiveCell) = True
ThisWorkbook.Save
```